# go get/build can't resolve a local-only project package

Tags: go

```
project.go:6:2: cannot find package "example.com/project/package" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.1.2/libexec/src/pkg/example.com/project/package (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/me/go/src/example.com/project/package (from $GOPATH)


Fetching https://example.com/project/package?go-get=1 
ignoring https fetch with status code 404 Fetching http://example.com/project/package?go-get=1 
Parsing meta tags from http://example.com/project/package?go-get=1 (status code 404)     
import "example.com/project/package": parse http://example.com/project/package?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags 
package example.com/project/package: unrecognized import path "example.com/project/package"
```

Why can't go get/build find the local package. I understand go get will fail on my repo because it's bare, but it seems like go get is completely ignoring the local file, forcing me to commit and push my code before I can compile it. This is, per the snippet, OSX 10.8 and Go 1.1.2 installed via brew. GOPATH is set to /Users/me/go and GOROOT is empty.

I should note that I don't have this problem at all when using go get in gitbash on my Windows machine. I've tried all the google-fu I can think of to search this, but everyone claims you can use relative "project/package" imports, which also completely fail in this case.

Comment: `go get` is for getting external stuff, it won't work for local code. But anyway: You are not supposed to build with `go get`. Local code building is done with `go build`. So where is the issue? What are you really doing?

Comment: The first output is from go build, the second is from go get. I find that the plugin with sublime text won't include autocomplete for packages if I haven't run build or get successfully first. I generally have a bash script running in a shell that runs get and reports errors. I use get over build because get will also resolve any new external dependencies I also happen to add that tick.
Nothing I'm doing is magic, it's all very plain go, and builds fine on Windows. Only new thing is a private repo that 404s because it's bare. But that shouldn't matter since the source is already in my $GOPATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading from go1.1.2 to go1.2 through `brew upgrade go` fixed this problem

Answer (score 2):

You can work with code locally without having pushed it - you just need your folder structure to mimic the import path.

Put your library code inside a `src/` directory, with a folder structure mimicking the import path:

```
[15:42] foa:home $ tree
.
├── myprogram.go
└── src
    └── example.com
        └── project
            └── mypackage
                └── mypackage.go
```

Then set GOPATH to the directory that has `src/` in it, and you'll be able to build the project:

```
[15:42] foa:home $ export GOPATH=`pwd`
[15:42] foa:home $ go build
```

Here's `myprogram.go`:

```
package main

import "example.com/project/mypackage"

func main() {
    mypackage.Run()
}
```

And `mypackage.go`:

```
package mypackage

import "fmt"

func Run() {
    fmt.Println("It works.")
}
```

It's common to lay out your working directories like this, and then root the actual git repositories at the lowest level (e.g. in `src/example.com/project/mypackage`) so that they work cleanly with `go get` and `go install` for other users.

Comment: This is not the issue. I've since tried changing the project path from my.domain.com to github.com, and updated all the import paths. go get, nor go build, complain when I run them, even though the github user path is fake and the project name doesn't exist. Why does go treat my private domain import path differently? And only on OSX 10.8? To reiterate, the layout has no problems on my Windows machine running the same version of Go.